# Overwrite WC_Shortcode_Cart::output in WooComerce

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

My goal is to override the checkout page which contains `cart.php` and `form-checkout.php`.

For some reason, I override the `form-checkout.php` template via my theme. I included the cart inside it using:

```
 <?php wc_get_template( 'cart/cart.php' ); ?>
```

My problem is that `cart.php` contains several similar `id` attributes, so I only hide the cart above the form checkout with some CSS, but how to prevent some `id` duplication. I would like to remove it, but the template is called by `WC_Shortcode_Cart::output`.

So how can I overwrite `WC_Shortcode_Cart::output` or is there another proper way to do this?

Comment: Note that `<?php wc_get_template( 'cart/cart.php' ); ?>` added to `form-checkout.php` template, doesn't use `WC_Shortcode_Cart::output()`. So you need **also** to override the `cart/cart.php` template file via your theme, to make structural changes to the cart HTML output, without forgetting that `cart/cart.php` calls also `cart/cart-item-data.php`, `cart/cart-totals.php`, `cart/cross-sells.php`…